# How can i check the order of column values(by date) for every unique id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table, Activity:

```
| ID | Date of activity    | activity |
|----|---------------------|----------|
| 1  | 2016-05-01T13:45:03 | a        |
| 1  | 2016-05-02T13:45:03 | b        |
| 1  | 2016-05-03T13:45:03 | a        |
| 1  | 2016-05-04T13:45:03 | b        |
| 2  | 2016-05-01T13:45:03 | b        |
| 2  | 2016-05-02T13:45:03 | b        |
```

and this table:

```
| id | Right order |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | yes         |
| 2  | no          |
```

How can I check for every ID if the order of the activities is sumiliar to this order for example  ?

```
 a b a b a b  ..
```

of course i'll check according to activity date

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is a bit confuse. Show us an example of the output.

Comment: From the data you posted this is impossible. By definition a table is an unordered set and you have nothing that would provide a consistent order.

Comment: the wright table is the output i want it , i want to check the order according to date , i take the earliest activity value to check if it's equal to -a- and then the second eariliest activity to check if it's -b- and on .. if the order is similiar to a b a b a... then i put as yes for this ID

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+ you could use [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), and then the `min()` of a `case` expression that follows your logic like so:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
      , prev_activity = lag(activity) over (partition by id order by date_of_activity)
  from t
)
select id
  , right_order = min(case
      when activity = 'a' and isnull(prev_activity,'b')<>'b' then 'no'
      when activity = 'b' and isnull(prev_activity,'b')<>'a' then 'no'
      else 'yes'
    end)
from cte
group by id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NQQF78056

returns:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | right_order |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | yes         |
|  2 | no          |
+----+-------------+
```

---

Prior to SQL Server 2012 you can use `outer apply()` to get the previous activity instead of `lag()` like so:

```
select id
  , right_order = min(case
      when activity = 'a' and isnull(prev_activity,'b')<>'b' then 'no'
      when activity = 'b' and isnull(prev_activity,'b')<>'a' then 'no'
      else 'yes'
    end)
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 prev_activity = i.activity
    from t as i
    where i.id = t.id
      and i.date_of_activity < t.date_of_activity
    order by i.date_of_activity desc
    ) x
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

> **EDITED - Allows for variable number of Patterns per ID**

Perhaps another approach

**Example**

```
Declare @Pat varchar(max)='a b'
Declare @Cnt int = 2

Select ID
      ,RightOrder = case when rtrim(replicate(@Pat+' ',Hits/@Cnt)) = (Select Stuff((Select ' ' +activity From t Where id=A.id order by date_of_activity For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end
 From (Select ID,hits=count(*) from t group by id) A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RightOrder
1   Yes
2   No
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
case when sum(flag)=0 and cnt_per_id%2=0 
     and max(case when rnum=1 then activity end) = 'a' 
     and max(case when rnum=2 then activity end) = 'b' 
     and min_activity = 'a' and max_activity = 'b'
then 'yes' else 'no' end as RightOrder
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by id order by activitydate) as rnum
      ,count(*) over(partition by id) as cnt_per_id
      ,min(activity) over(partition by id) as min_activity
      ,max(activity) over(partition by id) as max_activity
      ,case when lag(activity) over(partition by id order by activitydate)=activity then 1 else 0 end as flag
      from tbl t
     ) t
group by id,cnt_per_id,max_activity,min_activity
```

Based on the explanation the following logic has to be implemented for rightorder.

- Check if the number of rows per id are even (Remove this condition if there can be an odd number of rows like a,b,a or a,b,a,b,a and so on)
- First row contains `a` and second `b`, min activity is `a` and max activity is `b` for an id.
- Sum of flags (set using `lag`) should be 0